# Breaking constraints when resizing buttons in interface builder

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I am trying to get two rows of buttons to resize as the screen resizes. The width and the height must be the same for all the buttons on the screen. However I get this result with the button on the bottom right a different size to the rest. The console also complains that it is unable to satisfy all the constraints. Can't for the life of me fix it.

[image]

The link to my project is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8u2bccvkywoorg/buttons.zip?dl=0

I do my constraints like so:

1.) 
First select container 1, pin bottom, trailing and leading. Select all buttons in container 1, pin top, bottom, leading, trailing and aspect ratio.

2.) 
Select container 2, pin bottom, leading and trailing. Select all buttons in container 2, pin top, bottom, leading, trailing and aspect ratio.

3.)
Select all buttons in container 1 and container 2. Pin equal width and equal height.

Could someone please help me out and tell me what I might be doing wrong here please?